# android layout did not render expected appearance for low resolution(480x800)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have problem to render expected output in Samsung Galaxy Express and also I test the application output in 5.1" WVGA(5.1" 480x800 mdpi) virtual device, I got the same out put like this.

[image]

(each cell have different image)

I put the XML layout, that is remote_xbox_extended.xml in following folders.

[image]

this is the remote_xbox_extended.xml

```
<LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#000000">

                <LinearLayout android:visibility="gone" android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxRow1" android:layout_weight="110" android:layout_height="0px" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:baselineAligned="false">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="297dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.93"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                            android:text="Device Name"
                            android:id="@+id/txtDeviceName_extened" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="104dp"
                            android:layout_height="29dp">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:id="@+id/imgViewOnlineOffline_extened"
                                android:background="@drawable/green_circle"
                                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:text="Online"
                                android:id="@+id/txtOnline_extened"
                                android:textColor="#ff05ff5f" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- this is the only row that is added compared to the normal "lowres" version of the layout. -->

                <LinearLayout android:visibility="gone" android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxRowSections" android:layout_weight="110.05" android:layout_height="0px" android:layout_width="match_parent">
                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxRow2" android:layout_weight="112" android:layout_height="0px" android:layout_width="match_parent">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_weight="142"
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxImgBtnVolumeDown"
                        android:background="@drawable/xbmc_remote_remote_sounddown"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_weight="142"
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/xbmc_remote_remote_soundmute"
                        android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxImgBtnVolume"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_weight="142"
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxImgBtnVolumeUp"
                        android:background="@drawable/xbmc_remote_remote_soundup"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxRow3"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="50">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_weight="110"
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxImgBtnBack"
                        android:background="@drawable/xbmc_remote_remote_goback"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxRow4"
                    android:layout_weight="175"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="#ff000000">

                    <Button android:layout_weight="110" android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxImgBtnUp"
                        android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:background="@drawable/xbmc_remote_remote_arrowup" android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxRow5" android:layout_weight="300" android:layout_height="0px" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="#ff000000">
                    <Button android:layout_weight="110" android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxImgBtnLeft"
                        android:background="@drawable/xbmc_remote_remote_arrowleft" android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        />
                    <Button android:layout_weight="110"  android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxImgBtnSelect"
                        android:background="@drawable/xbmc_remote_remote_ok" android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"  />
                    <Button android:layout_weight="110" android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxImgBtnRight"
                        android:background="@drawable/xbmc_remote_remote_arrowright" android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxRow6"
                    android:layout_weight="165"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent">

                    <Button android:layout_weight="110" android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxImgBtnDown"
                        android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/xbmc_remote_remote_arrowdown" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxRow7"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="50" >

                    <Button
                        android:layout_weight="110"
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxImgBtnfullscreen"
                        android:background="@drawable/xbmc_remote_remote_fullscreen"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxRow8"
                    android:layout_weight="112"
                    android:layout_height="0px"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" >

                    <Button
                        android:layout_weight="142"
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/xbmc_remote_remote_menu"
                        android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxImgBtnTitle"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_weight="142"
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxImgBtnGestuer"
                        android:background="@drawable/xbmc_remote_remote_gestuer"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_weight="142"
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxImgBtnkeyboad"
                        android:background="@drawable/xbmc_remote_remote_keyboard"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxRow9" android:layout_weight="112" android:layout_height="0px" android:layout_width="match_parent">
                    <Button android:layout_weight="142" android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/xbmc_remote_remote_rewind"
                        android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxImgBtnSeekBack" android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
                    <Button android:layout_weight="142" android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxImgBtnPlay"
                        android:background="@drawable/xbmc_remote_remote_playpause" android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
                    <Button android:layout_weight="142" android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxImgBtnSeekForward"
                        android:background="@drawable/xbmc_remote_remote_fastforward" android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxRow10" android:layout_weight="112" android:layout_height="0px" android:layout_width="match_parent">
                    <Button android:layout_weight="142" android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxImgBtnPrevious"
                        android:background="@drawable/xbmc_remote_remote_playprevious" android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
                    <Button android:layout_weight="142" android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxImgBtnStop"
                        android:background="@drawable/xbmc_remote_remote_stop" android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

                    <Button android:layout_weight="142" android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/RemoteXboxImgBtnNext"
                        android:background="@drawable/xbmc_remote_remote_playnext" android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

each button refers to a XML that is represent two images.Following code is a example for that

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/ic_remote_soundlow_keypressed"  />
            </item>
          <item>
            <!--<item android:bottom="-1dp" android:left="0dp" android:right="-1dp" android:top="0dp">-->
                <shape>

                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffffffff" />
                    <!-- <corners android:radius="5dp" />-->
                    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item android:state_enabled="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/ic_remote_soundlow" />
            </item>
            <item>
            <!--<item android:bottom="-1dp" android:left="0dp" android:right="-1dp" android:top="0dp">-->
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">

                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffffffff" />
                    <!-- <corners android:radius="5dp" />-->
                    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

image resolution is 96x80 png(8-bit color)

I found the root cause for this error,In the second xml when I modify following(I remove the code that create the border for image) it will show the image but I loss the border that I have added in this xml.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:gravity="fill" android:src="@drawable/ic_remote_soundlow_keypressed"  />
            </item>
          
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item android:state_enabled="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:gravity="fill" android:src="@drawable/ic_remote_soundlow" />
            </item>

        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

what is the reason for getting above broken view.How can I fix this?

Comment: Post the contents of the xml files, are you using px as unit for dimensions?

Comment: different layout_weight value without its sum is confusing. hope you are not  using it as width of the view (in px)

Comment: I change the layout_weight also but problem same as early..